# Graphs implementation in java

Tags: java, graph, implementation

I am trying to create a Graph class that uses another class, the Vertex class to represent all the vertices of the graph. I am not sure if I need an Edge class that will represent the possible connections between two vertices, because every vertex can keep track of the other nodes it is connected to. But I am not sure if this is correct. What do you think?

Thank you.

Comment: Q: Is this "homework"?  If so, please flag it as such.  In any case, take a look at this:  http://en.literateprograms.org/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm_%28Java%29

Comment: It is not homework. I know how to implement the class with and without using the edge class. I just want to know if it is correct without the Edge class. Anw thanks for the link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to use an `Edge` class. You can use adjacency lists and still represent an **unweighted** graph correctly. For a weighted graph you need a way to represent edge costs, and thus using an `Edge` class would be appropriate.

```
class Graph<E> {
    private List<Vertex<E>> vertices;

    private static class Vertex<E> {
        E elem;
        List<Vertex<E>> neighbors;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I was thinking. To keep track of the other vertices without using an Edge class at all. Thank you!!!!

Comment: All well and good until you need a weighted directed graph. Then you'll need metadata or better yet an Edge class.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, a [*representation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29#Representations) is chosen based in its suitability to the intended use. In this simple example, [`GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) uses nothing more than a `List<Edge>` as its model.