# Java - Graphics - adding another shape on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, drawing

I've got a class that makes a JFrame and adds a panel on it
and the second one extends the JPanel and paints on it

The first one (JFrame)

```
class MyWindow {

void qwe() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("qwe");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    frame.add(panel);}}
```

and the second one (JPanel)

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(50,50,90,70);
}

public void addShape() {
    Graphics g = this.getGraphics();

    Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;

    gg.drawString("qwe",20,20);}}
```

---

**how can i add a String on the JPanel by using the addShape() method ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a concrete example of @camickr's point, note that `MyPanel` already override's `paintComponent()`, so you can pass a reference to the `Graphics` context to `addShape()`. Additionally,

- Be sure to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)`.
- Override `getPreferredSize()` to establish the component's preferred size.
- Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manipulated *only* on the [event dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyWindow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MyWindow().qwe();
            }
        });
    }

    void qwe() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("qwe");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawRect(50, 50, 90, 70);
            addShape(g);
        }

        public void addShape(Graphics g) {
            g.drawString("qwe", 20, 20);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does the `addShape` method need to "get" the 'g' from the `paintComponent` method ?

Comment: That's the one set up to change pixels in the host's peer component. The alternative is to write to the pixels of a `BufferedImage` and later update the screen.

Comment: Well that didn't help me much, but at least now I know what to write to make it work... so thanks

Comment: Indeed, it's not very satisfying. At the most basic level, your Java program has to share the host's pixels, which aren't always accessible to your program.

Comment: And what should I do, when I want the addShape(Graphics g) method to be ran independently and not everytime I add the MyPanel on a JFrame. Thats what I would want to know the most

Comment: Think of how your program might alter an underlying _model_, which the view can render, as suggested in the example cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10255573/230513).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the getGraphics() method of your component to do custom painting. This type of painting is only temporary and will be lost the next time Swing determines the component needs to be painted.

Custom painting should always be done in the paintComponent() method of your component.

See [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for the two commons was to do what you want.